# how to import data from other database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, data-migration

I have 2 databases in SQL Server 2005.
I want a functionality that i have same table structure in 2 database for example i have a same table named as testData in 2 database named as dbTest1 and dbTest2.

Now i want a single query through which i can add all the records from table testData of database dbTest2 into table testData of database dbTest1.

I tried to use following query

insert into dbTest1.testData values select * from dbTest2.testData

but this query is not running and giving error.

I also tried

insert into dbTest1.testData(col1,col2,col3) values select * from dbTest2.testData
but this also gives error that "Invalid object name dbTest2.testData"

Could any one help in this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `dbTest2.testData` with `dbTest2..testData` - you have to specify 3 things (or optionally leave the middle blank for dbo).

i.e.

```
insert into dbTest1..testData
select * from dbTest2..testData
```

If the table doesn't already exist in dbTest1, you can do this:

```
select * 
into dbTest1..testData
from dbTest2..testData
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all column names in query.

```
insert into dbTest1.dbo.testData(col1,col2,col3) select * from dbTest2.dbo.testData
```

Comment: Its giving following error "Invalid object name dbTest2.testData"

Comment: -1 - you don't need to specify the columns if you have the same structure in both (although it is advisable for future-proofing against changes).  The actual problem is something different as per my answer.

Comment: @Sumit Gupta, my fault, i forgot about dbo, check updated answer